# How to pass in a variable to a .then() callback function from an outer scope?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I have an API receiving an request and doing some querys and validation.

I want to use the `response` reference from the route inside the `findUserPlayer` function so I can send something to the client. The `findUser` function will return a `data` object that will be used on `findUserPlayer`.

```
var api = express.Router();

api.post('/signup', function (request, response) {

    UserModel.find(req.body)
        .then(findUser, createUser)
        .then(findUserPlayer, createUserPlayer);
});

var findUserPlayer = function (data, res) {
    //...
    res.json(object);
};
```

- I've tried calling `findUserPlayer(data, res)`, which gives me 'data is not defined'.
- I've tried calling `findUserPlayer(res)`, which will override `data`.

How can I use the `response` object inside that callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly passing *findUserPlayer* function as a success handler, you can define a success handler function while will then call findUserPlayer.

```
var api = express.Router();

api.post('/signup', function (request, response) {

    UserModel.find(req.body)
        .then(findUser, createUser)
        .then(function(data) {
            return findUserPlayer(data, response);
        }, createUserPlayer);
});

var findUserPlayer = function (data, res) {
    //...
    res.json(object);
};
```

Comment: `return findUserPlayer`? Why not calling  it.

Comment: @KunalKapadia: Omitting the `return` is in fact a mistake

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is a very flexible language which means there are many ways you can handle this, one of the easiest (in terms of minimum code change) is to reverse the order of arguments in `findUserPlayer` and binding your context (`.bind(response)`).

But that would be a poor design choice. There's no reason for a function that "finds a user" to deal with responses or json. It's out of this functions scope and responsibility. The request handler is the one that should deal with formatting a relevant response, and I'd do that by returning the relevant data in the promise chain and eventually:

```
.then(function(data) {
   response.json(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of lodash and sometimes to a fault, but thought I would add the following using lodash's partialRight function.

```
var _ = require('lodash');
...
UserModel.find(req.body)
    .then(findUser, createUser)
    .then(_.partialRight(findUserPlayer, response), createUserPlayer);
```

`_.partialRight` returns a new function with the partials appended to the new function. The first argument of `_.partialRight` is the function we want to append the arguments to. The subsequent arguments are the args we want to append to the function.

I'm assuming the following function signature: `findUserPlayer(data, response)`. `_.partialRight` appends the response object to the new function. The new function signature looks like this now: `function (data)`.

[documentation](http://devdocs.io/lodash/index#partialRight)